# Prevent MatLab nesting variables when saving/loading?

Tags: matlab

I have a variable called sources that contains eight numbers:

```
sources =

    0.6028
    0.7112
    0.2217
    0.1174
    0.2967
    0.3188
    0.4242
    0.5079
```

I save it using `save('sources.mat', 'sources');` and then load it again using `sources = load('sources.mat');`

However it is no longer just an array of eight numbers, the sources variable is now:

```
sources = 

    sources: [8x1 double]
```

Is there any way to get rid of this nesting when saving/loading? It's hassle having to always retrieve the nested variables after loading them. When I use `sources = load('sources.mat');` I would like to get back

```
sources =

    0.6028
    0.7112
    0.2217
    0.1174
    0.2967
    0.3188
    0.4242
    0.5079
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the simplest scenario as the one you show us, you can create an inline function that extracts your data:

```
loadAndExtract = @(varname) arrayfun(@(x) x.(varname), load(varname));
```

now you can just load your data as a matrix:

```
sources = loadAndExtract('sources.mat'); % load and extract data
```

The drawback of this approach is that you are forced to match name of the file and name of the variable. If this is a problem for you you can make the function slightly more complex:

```
loadAndExtract = @(dataName,varname) arrayfun(@(x) x.(varname), load(dataName));
```

now if you load your data with a specific name:

```
save('mySources','sources');
```

you can still load it by specifying the name of the variable and name of the file.

```
sources = loadAndExtract('mySources','sources');
```

In principle you can write the function to extract multiple data from the same file, but then the inline function gets more and more complex and I would suggest to write is as a separate function.

Comment: I like to use inline functions for these smalls problems because they increase portability of the code and the overall readibilty (copared to an external function, or to repeating the same operation over and over on the same script). But I know that not everybody agrees with me.